# Scrolling vertically within horizontal 'tabs'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently making a website as part of a school project. In this website, i wanted to try something fun, new and different. Unfortunately, I've gone and dug myself a deeeeeep hole and it is due in too soon, so i would really appreciate any help.
And now to the issue at hand:

---

I decided to make four pages; only those pages are more like 'tabs' each within their own div. When a link is clicked, a small piece of javascript is run to set the left property to x*screenWidth pixels, where x equals a number relative to the currently viewed page.
i.e.
*if i am viewing page 1 then for page 0 x=-1; for page 2 x=2; and for page 3 x=3.
Likewise if page 3 is being viewed for page 0 x=-3; for page 1 x=-2; and for page 2 x=-1.*

Then by applying position: fixed; to each of the div id's of the tabs and a transition i can do a neat little sliding animation as i switch between the different pages with the others just fixed off to the left or right out of the view-port area.

My issue is that, on each of these tabs, i also need to be able to scroll vertically because i can't see most of my content. Unfortunately, with the divs fixed as they are, this does not appear possible. I've tried the other position properties: relative was the closest to working but each of the tabs ended up sort of cascading with each page further from the top - e.g.

```
page 0
       page 1
              page 2
                     page 3
```

Also, i tried floating the elements at the same time but that didn't work either.

Here is a mock-up of my code for you to see in JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/OliverGriffin/W47pG/. Unfortunately, it *doesn't actually work* in JS Fiddle so i created a *very* rough html document with all of what i think is the relevant code. Just copy and paste this into an HTML document and run.

Here is the CSS (because the stack overflow code thing was playing up for me) - just place this at the top of the html document in <style> tags.

```
#container {
    display: block;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
}
#homeTab, #xTab, #yTab, #zTab {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    transition: 2s;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    -moz-transition: 2s;
    -o-transition: 2s;
    -ms-transition: 2s;
}
```

And then the HTML and JavaScript, beneath that:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#homeTab" onClick="page(0);" title="Home">home</a>
            <a href="#xTab" onClick="page(1);" title="x">page x</a>
            <a href="#yTab" onClick="page(2);" title="y">page y</a>
            <a href="#zTab" onClick="page(3);" title="z">page z</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id='container'>
        <div id="homeTab">
            <p>Home page</p>
        </div>
        <div id="xTab">
            <p>Page X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X</p>
        </div>
        <div id="yTab">
            <p>Page Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y</p>
        </div>
        <div id="zTab">
            <p>Page Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var homeTab = document.getElementById('homeTab');
var xTab = document.getElementById('xTab');
var yTab = document.getElementById('yTab');
var zTab = document.getElementById('zTab');

if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
    var vpwidth = window.innerWidth;
}

homeTab.style.width = vpwidth + 'px';
xTab.style.width = vpwidth + 'px';
yTab.style.width = vpwidth + 'px';
zTab.style.width = vpwidth + 'px';

/** POSITIONS THE TABS BASED ON WHICH TAB SHOULD BE SHOWING **/
function page(tab) {
    switch (tab) {
        case 0:
            homeTab.style.left = '0px';
            xTab.style.left = vpwidth + 'px';
            yTab.style.left = 2 * vpwidth + 'px';
            zTab.style.left = 3 * vpwidth + 'px';

            break;
        case 1:
            homeTab.style.left = (0 - vpwidth) + 'px';
            xTab.style.left = '0px';
            yTab.style.left = vpwidth + 'px';
            zTab.style.left = 2 * vpwidth + 'px';
            break;
        case 2:
            homeTab.style.left = (0 - 2 * vpwidth) + 'px';
            xTab.style.left = (0 - vpwidth) + 'px';
            yTab.style.left = '0px';
            zTab.style.left = vpwidth + 'px';
            break;
        case 3:
            homeTab.style.left = (0 - 3 * vpwidth) + 'px';
            xTab.style.left = (0 - 2 * vpwidth) + 'px';
            yTab.style.left = (0 - vpwidth) + 'px';
            zTab.style.left = '0px';
            break;
        default:
            homeTab.style.left = '0px';
            xTab.style.left = vpwidth + 'px';
            yTab.style.left = 2 * vpwidth + 'px';
            zTab.style.left = 3 * vpwidth + 'px';
            break;
    }
}
page(0);
</script>
```

I would really appreciate a way to scroll vertically while still keeping my horizontal tabs if possible. Is there a better way i could be doing this? Thanks for your time.

*P.s. I would prefer if answers did not involve jquery. I don't know how to use it and i don't have enough time to learn.*

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something simple like this? (involve only overflow attribute) http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/C8KgM/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
      #container {
        display: block;
      }

      nav {
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
      }

      #homeTab, #xTab, #yTab, #zTab {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        transition: 2s;
        -webkit-transition: 2s;
        -moz-transition: 2s;
        -o-transition: 2s;
        -ms-transition: 2s;
      }

      .ttab{
      height:300px;
      overflow-y:scroll;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href="#homeTab" onclick="page(0);" title="Home">home</a>
      <a href="#xTab" onclick="page(1);" title="x">page x</a>
      <a href="#yTab" onclick="page(2);" title="y">page y</a>
      <a href="#zTab" onclick="page(3);" title="z">page z</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id='container'>
    <div id="homeTab">
      <p>Home page</p>
    </div>
    <div id="xTab" class="ttab">
      <p>Page X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X<br>X</p>
    </div>
    <div id="yTab" class="ttab">
      <p>Page Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y<br>Y</p>
    </div>
    <div id="zTab" class="ttab">
      <p>Page Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z<br>Z</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  var homeTab = document.getElementById('homeTab');
  var xTab = document.getElementById('xTab');
  var yTab = document.getElementById('yTab');
  var zTab = document.getElementById('zTab');

  if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
    var vpwidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  homeTab.style.width = vpwidth + 'px';
  xTab.style.width = vpwidth + 'px';
  yTab.style.width = vpwidth + 'px';
  zTab.style.width = vpwidth + 'px';

  /** POSITIONS THE TABS BASED ON WHICH TAB SHOULD BE SHOWING **/
  function page(tab) {
    switch (tab) {
      case 0:
        homeTab.style.left = '0px';
        xTab.style.left = vpwidth + 'px';
        yTab.style.left = 2 * vpwidth + 'px';
        zTab.style.left = 3 * vpwidth + 'px';

        break;
      case 1:
        homeTab.style.left = (0 - vpwidth) + 'px';
        xTab.style.left = '0px';
        yTab.style.left = vpwidth + 'px';
        zTab.style.left = 2 * vpwidth + 'px';
        break;
      case 2:
        homeTab.style.left = (0 - 2 * vpwidth) + 'px';
        xTab.style.left = (0 - vpwidth) + 'px';
        yTab.style.left = '0px';
        zTab.style.left = vpwidth + 'px';
        break;
      case 3:
        homeTab.style.left = (0 - 3 * vpwidth) + 'px';
        xTab.style.left = (0 - 2 * vpwidth) + 'px';
        yTab.style.left = (0 - vpwidth) + 'px';
        zTab.style.left = '0px';
        break;
      default:
        homeTab.style.left = '0px';
        xTab.style.left = vpwidth + 'px';
        yTab.style.left = 2 * vpwidth + 'px';
        zTab.style.left = 3 * vpwidth + 'px';
        break;
    }
  }
  page(0);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried overflow-y:scroll; previously but to no avail. I now see that i needed to specify a height in order for it to work... :)